# SQL Anywhere Error -824: Illegal reference to correlation name tableName

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

When I run this script on Sybase IQ:

```
declare @YEAR  int=2017
declare @MON   int=6
declare @DAY  int=7

update MainTable

set MainTable.Amount=(X.Number+Y.Number),
    MainTable.Total=(X.Total+Y.Total)

from (select 'Number'= count(*), 'Total'=case when SUM(T1_Total) is null then 0 else SUM(T1_Total) end
       from Table1    
       where  T1_Account_NO=MainTable.Account_NO 
       and    T1_SENTRY_YEAR=@YEAR and T1_SENTRY_MON=@MON and T1_SENTRY_DAY=@DAY) X,
     (select 'Number'= count(*), 'Total'=case when SUM(T2_TOTAL) is null then 0 else SUM(T2_TOTAL) end 
       from Table2  where T2_Account_NO = MainTable.Account_NO 
       and  T2_YEAR=@YEAR and T2_MON=@MON and T2_DAY=@DAY )Y 

where       MainTable.YEAR=@YEAR
      and   MainTable.MON = @MON
      and   MainTable.DAY=@DAY
```

I got an error like this : " SQL Anywhere Error -824: Illegal reference to correlation name MainTable"

How can I surpass this problem?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Have you tried adding MainTable to the `from` clause, eg:</s>

```
update Maintable
set    ...
from   MainTable,
       (select ... )X,
       (select ... )Y
where  ...
```

---

NOTE: I work with Sybase ASE, which does not allow 'external' correlation names to be referenced within derived tables, so I'm wondering if SQLAnywhere has a similar limitation ... ?

What happens if you pull the MainTable joins out to the top-most level of the query, eg:

```
declare @YEAR  int=2017
declare @MON   int=6
declare @DAY  int=7

update MainTable

set MainTable.Amount=(X.Number+Y.Number),
    MainTable.Total=(X.Total+Y.Total)

from (select T1_account_NO, 'Number'= count(*), 'Total'=case when SUM(T1_Total) is null then 0 else SUM(T1_Total) end
       from Table1    
       where  T1_SENTRY_YEAR=@YEAR and T1_SENTRY_MON=@MON and T1_SENTRY_DAY=@DAY
       group by T1_Account_NO) X,
     (select T2_Account_NO, 'Number'= count(*), 'Total'=case when SUM(T2_TOTAL) is null then 0 else SUM(T2_TOTAL) end 
       from Table2  where T2_YEAR=@YEAR and T2_MON=@MON and T2_DAY=@DAY 
       group by T2_Account_NO)Y 

where       MainTable.YEAR=@YEAR
      and   MainTable.MON = @MON
      and   MainTable.DAY=@DAY
      and   MainTable.Account_NO = X.T1_Account_NO
      and   MainTable.Account_NO = Y.T2_Account_NO
```

One potential performance-related downside would be if the derived tables now generate a large set of records that won't be joined with MainTable (unless the SQLAnywhere query engine is able to flatten the query in some way ... ???).

---

If this is an issue of not allowing 'external' correlation names in derived tables, another (obvious ?) solution would be to create a couple #temp tables from the results of joining MainTable with Table1/Table2, then perform the update of MainTable as a join with the #temp tables. [Possibly indexing the #temp tables if the data volumes are large enough to justify, performance-wise, the indexes.]

Comment: Hmmm, I'm wondering if SQLAnywhere is like ASE in that it does not support correlated names 'passed into' derived tables, ie, the derived table is not allowed to reference external table/view/correlation names? if that's the case, let me update my answer with another idea ... give me a few minutes ...

Comment: thanx for you useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding MainTable to the FROM clause?

Answer (score 0):

I surpass this problem like this:

```
declare @YEAR  int=2017
declare @MON   int=6
declare @DAY   int=7

update MainTable
set MainTable.Amount= (X.Number),
    MainTable.Total = (X.Total)
from (select T1_Account_NO,'Number'= count(*), 'Total'=case when SUM(T1_Total) is null then 0 else SUM(T1_Total) end
       from Table1    
       where T1_SENTRY_YEAR=@YEAR and T1_SENTRY_MON=@MON and T1_SENTRY_DAY=@DAY
       group by T1_Account_NO) X,
where  X.T1_Account_NO=MainTable.Account_NO
      and   MainTable.YEAR=@YEAR
      and   MainTable.MON = @MON
      and   MainTable.DAY=@DAY


update MainTable
set MainTable.Amount= coalesce(MainTable.Amount,0)+(Y.Number),
    MainTable.Total = coalesce(MainTable.Total,0)+(Y.Total)
     (select T2_Account_NO,'Number'= count(*), 'Total'=case when SUM(T2_TOTAL) is null then 0 else SUM(T2_TOTAL) end 
       from Table2  
       where T2_YEAR=@YEAR and T2_MON=@MON and T2_DAY=@DAY 
       group by T2_Account_NO) Y 

where       MainTable.YEAR=@YEAR
      and   MainTable.MON = @MON
      and   MainTable.DAY=@DAY
      and   Y.T2_Account_NO = MainTable.Account_NO
```

I have seperated update script the two parts.